# BMI with exception handling python

Tags: python, syntax, exception

I need help with this code I am trying to apply, a short time ago I ran a bmi calculator in index and now I am trying to update that code with exception handling. So far the portions don't give me errors they just run strangely together. For example, when it prompts "Enter the user's name or '0' to quit" it doesn't actually end the process it continues on to the exception process. Can someone help me write this more efficiently. here is my code this is updated, the issue I am specifically having now is the program is not terminating when the user enters '0':

```
def bmi_calculator():
end = False

print("Welcome to the BMI Calculator!")

while end == False:

    user = input("Enter student's name or '0' to quit: ")
    if user == "0":
        print("end of report!")
        end = True
    else:
        print("Lets gather your information,", user)
        break

flag='yes'
while flag != 'no':
    #Exception block for catching non integer inputs
    try:
        #Prompting user to input weight
        weight = int(input('Enter your weight in pounds : '))
        if weight == 0:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print ('Oops!! Kindly enter non-zero numbers only.')
        flag = input('Do you want to try again? yes/no : ')
        continue

    try:
        #Prompting user to input height
        height = float(input('Enter your height in inches : '))
        if height == 0:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print ('Oops!! Kindly enter non-zero numbers only.')
        flag = input('Do you want to try again? yes/no : ')
        continue

    #Formula for calculating BMI
    BMI = round(weight * 703/(height*height), 2)
    return (BMI)
print(" Your bmi is:", bmi_calculator())
```

Comment: Try using `pass` instead of `continue`

Comment: `while end == False` has no indented block following so there is no looping code. You might want to put a `while` around the main module code after the `def`s?

Comment: the issue that I am having right now is that the code is not terminating when someone enters '0' I am about to post updated code